# Python assign the total number to in ID

Tags: python, csv

**pandas extension is not allow to use**

I have a CSV file with ID column (Username) and two numeric columns. In base Python I want to get the ID and the sum of Auto and Manual Score, then generate another CSV with the result.

Example CSV:

```
Username  Auto Score  Manual Score
1234      1
1234      1 
1234      1      
1234                  1.5
345       1
345       1
345                   2
133       1
133       1
133                   2.5
```

And I want to mergin the same username as one and sum up the auto Score and Manual Score as follow:

```
Username  Total Score
1234      4.5
345       3
133       3.5
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv
List = []
with open("exam_for_2019.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        auto_score = float(row['Auto Score']) if row['Auto Score'].strip() else 0
        Manual_Score = float(row['Manual Score']) if row['Manual Score'].strip() else 0
        sum_row = float(auto_score) + float(Manual_Score)
        List.append(sum_row)
        sums = sum(List)
        print(sums)
```

I tired to assign the score into one list and sum it up.
Now the question is I don't know how to assign each total number based on Username, also when I run the code it only gives me a total number. How can I add all the scores up based on the username??

Comment: Add the csv to the question please

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Just edit the CSV example, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below  (Note that the data structure CSV_DATA replaces the actual csv but the concept is the same)

```
from collections import defaultdict

CSV_DATA = [['123', '1', ''], ['123', '1', ''], ['123', '1', ''], ['123', '', '1.5'], ['345', '2', ''],
            ['345', '2', ''], ['345', '2', ''], ['345', '', '2.5']]

data = defaultdict(float)
for entry in CSV_DATA:
    data[entry[0]] += (float(entry[1]) if entry[1] else 0)
    data[entry[0]] += (float(entry[2]) if entry[2] else 0)

for user_id, _sum in data.items():
    print('{} : {}'.format(user_id, _sum))
```

output

```
123 : 4.5
345 : 8.5
```